# "Required to do" vs. "required doing"

Tags: infinitives

> - Your employer is **required to deduct** a certain amount from your salary as a withstanding tax payable to the federal government.
> - 'Hamlet' is **required reading** [= must be read] for this course.

Would you kindly tell me the reason why in the first sentence, there is an infinitive after *required*, and in the second one a gerund?

Comment: @Andrew Leach Your edit is supposed to be the answer! :)

Comment: @Kris I don't believe so: the question is **Why** the infinitive is needed in the first case and **why** the gerund is needed in the second case. I didn't alter that question; I simply altered the text to be more relevant to that question.

Comment: I wonder why I am the only one on this page objecting to this being called a gerund. I would have expected everyone to immediately point out that *reading*, here, is indeed a full-fledged noun, and a noun only. It does not function one bit as a verb.

Comment: @RegDwigt: I don't know, the boundary between gerund and ossified noun is not so clear. I guess I would agree this is no ordinary gerund, at the very least.

Comment: @Cerberus I encourage you to try and modify that *reading* with an adverb. I am not seeing how you could.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I wanted to retain the version where the OP does **not** use the word *gerund* at all -- using *v+ing* instead. It could have been thoughtful on the OP's part, or it could be that the OP is not aware. Either way it makes a substantial difference.

Comment: @Kris the original version did use "gerund" alongside "v+ing". Not in the title, but in the last sentence of the body. In fact it outright equated a gerund to a v+ing, which of course is even worse than what we have now, as not every present participle is automatically used as a noun.

Answer (score 4):

I think all answers and comments so far, including mine, are really missing one crucial point.

The big thing here is that "required reading" is a [set phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase) that we use when we talk about books mandatory for some purpose, and particularly when talking about mandatory books for a course.

That reason, more than anything else, is why "required reading" is preferred here, even though "required to be read" would be grammatical and make a certain amount of sense.

Comment: OMG ur so smart would reading again. A++

Answer (score 3):

Note that in

> Your employer is **required** "to deduct" a certain amount from your salary …

*required* is a **verb**, and *deduct* is also a **verb**.

However, in

> 'Hamlet' is **required** "**reading**" (=must be read) for this course

*required* is an adjective to the gerund (behaving like a noun) *reading*.

It is not a case of merely adding *-ing* to a verb. Consider that *deduct* is a verb and *reading* is a noun.

Answer (score 0):

The important point is that, in each example, the subject of the sentence stands in a different relationship to the verb 'require'.

In the first, the subject is your 'employer' upon whom there is a requirement. Hence 'Your employer is required to deduct....'. 'Required', a past participle, acts as an adverb in qualification of 'is...to deduct'.

In the second example Hamlet, the subject, is not required to do anything. It is just that that play, is 'required reading'. Thus the past participle acts not in qualifying any verb but as an adjective to qualify the complement and gerund 'reading'.

Comment: It comes as surprise that *required* modifies *deduct*. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Kris No, as I said, it 'qualifies' 'is...to deduct'. One could have said 'Employer is 'is allowed to deduct/certain to deduct/ tempted to deduct/inclined to deduct/ etc. Note all the qualifiers are past participles. More qualified grammarians than me could give you a far more technical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native English speaker, and I would say: we require SOMEBODY to do something, but SOMETHING requires an action no matter who performs it. For example: my car **requires cleaning**, which can be done by whoever, but I can **require my son to clean it** as a punishment because he drove it without my permission.

Comment: Hello, Irina. You're introducing a third construction here. (a) 'I require my son to clean the car' (and passivised, 'Your employer is required to deduct a certain amount from your salary') is << require + NP + to-infinitive ... >>. (c) '_Hamlet_ is required reading' is essentially << S + copula + complement >> (cf '_Othello_ is a set text' >>. (b) 'My car requires/needs cleaning' is << V + V-ing >>, in this instance in a 'verb + object'  structure (as an 'echo question' is '_What_ does it need?')

Comment: Hello, Edwin, and thank you for the explanation.